# Calling Azure app service api from databricks notebook in azure using managed identity

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, databricks, azure-managed-identity

I need to call an .net core API, which is exposed via azure app service from databricks notebook.

I have tried several ways but the token validation never goes through, any link to the solution will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: “*any link to the solution will be highly appreciated.*” Questions seeking links to off-site resources are explicitly off-topic here per the scope of the site defined in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post your code and the error?

Comment: @AnupamChand Did you find a solution to the same? If so can you share your code

Comment: Databricks does not offer any managed identity authentication to other Azure services. For managed identity, there needs to be an identity created for Databricks within Azure AD and this functionality is not available yet.